# How to write a formula containing multiple picklist fields that populates a % field each time picklist marked "completed"

Tags: formula, picklist

```
IF(ISPICKVAL( X2_1_1_Team_Cleared_o_Work_Onsite__c , "Completed"), 0.33, 
IF(ISPICKVAL( X3_1_4_Chief_Scribe_Training__c , "Completed"), 0.66, 
IF(ISPICKVAL( x3_4_2__c , "Completed"), 1,  null)))
```

Basically I am trying to write a formula that when one picklist is marked as completed it updates a Percentage field to 33% and then when another picklist is marked as complete it marks it as 66%, lastly when a 3rd picklist is marked as completed it marks the field as 100% complete.

When the first field is marked as completed it does, in fact do as it should by marking the % field complete. However, when I mark the 2nd field as complete, it does nothing....unless I change the first field back to not started or in progress, then it will update to 66% percent. The problem is this would never happen, we use this object as a sort of checklist, so the 2nd field would never be completed without the first field first having been completed, and we would never go back to mark the first field as not completed.

I believe I am just missing a boolean logic component and probably getting the syntax wrong.

Comment: why not just reverse the order of the IFs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you check whether your first status is set to Completed. If it is, the percentage in your field will be 33%. If it is NOT true, then it will look at the second if-statement.

Try the following formula:

```
IF(ISPICKVAL( X2_1_1_Team_Cleared_o_Work_Onsite__c , "Completed"), 1/3, 0 ) + 
IF(ISPICKVAL( X3_1_4_Chief_Scribe_Training__c , "Completed"), 1/3, 0 ) + 
IF(ISPICKVAL( x3_4_2__c , "Completed"), 1/3, 0 )
```

It now checks every field for the Completed status and returns 33% if it's true. Then it shows the total percentage as a result.

Comment: You're missing the .33 in the 2nd line IF() statement, and have a comma instead of a decimal in the 3rd line. You should also be able to use 1/3 instead of .33 and then set the number of decimal places in the return type to 0, and it will round appropriately - so you'll get 1 instead of .99 if all three are checked.